# Ipad Photo Picker

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to get the IPAD to choose a photo from the photo album

```
            pickerController = [ [ UIImagePickerController alloc ] init ] ;
            pickerController.delegate   = self ;
            pickerController.editing    = NO ;
            pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

            [ self presentViewController : pickerController animated : YES completion : nil ] ;
```

The app keeps crashing when I use it on iPad, but works fine on iPhone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one got me before too. On the iPad if you specify a source type of `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` or `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotoAlbum` you need to present the image picker controller using a popover controller. If you try to present it modally, like you are doing, you will get an exception.

Not 100% required, but it's also a good idea to use the test to see what source types are available.

```
[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]
```

The source types are:

- `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`
- `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`
- `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`

This is how I solved this issue to test if it is an iPad or not.

```
if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){

    UIPopoverController* popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
    [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:selectVideoToViewButton.bounds inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}else {
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Yes, note step 4 of the overview in the docs -> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html